# HiveQL Difference between rows, columns based in Dates

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table (t_stocks) with data like this:

```
exchanged,stock_symbol,closing_date,closing_price
NSE,TCS,2009-08-09,2200.1
NSE,TCS,2009-08-10,2300.1
NSE,TCS,2009-08-11,12200.1
NSE,TCS,2009-08-12,22300.1
NSE,TCS,2009-09-09,2200.1
NSE,TCS,2009-09-10,2300.1
NSE,TCS,2009-09-11,12200.1
NSE,TCS,2009-09-12,22300.1
NSE,INFY,2009-08-09,2500.34
NSE,INFY,2009-08-10,1500.34
NSE,INFY,2009-08-09,7500.34
NSE,INFY,2009-08-10,14500.34
NSE,INFY,2009-09-09,2500.34
NSE,INFY,2009-09-10,1500.34
NSE,INFY,2009-09-09,7500.34
NSE,INFY,2009-09-10,14500.34
NSE,TCS,2010-08-09,2200.1
NSE,TCS,2010-08-10,2300.1
NSE,TCS,2010-08-11,12200.1
NSE,TCS,2010-08-12,22300.1
NSE,TCS,2010-09-09,2200.1
NSE,TCS,2010-09-10,2300.1
NSE,TCS,2010-09-11,12200.1
NSE,TCS,2010-09-12,22300.1
NSE,INFY,2010-08-09,2500.34
NSE,INFY,2010-08-10,1500.34
NSE,INFY,2010-08-09,7500.34
NSE,INFY,2010-08-10,14500.34
NSE,INFY,2010-09-09,2500.34
NSE,INFY,2010-09-10,1500.34
NSE,INFY,2010-09-09,7500.34
NSE,INFY,2010-09-10,14500.34
...
...
```

I would need to write a query which generate a report as follow.
exchanged, stock_symbol , closing_date , closing_price , yesterday_closing , diff_yesterday_price
(Price difference between Yesterday prices and today prices) with an output like this:

```
+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+--+
| exchanged      |     stock_symbol  |     closing_date  |     closing_price  |     yesterday_closing  | diff_yesterday_price  |
+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+--+
| NSE            | INFY              | 2009-08-09        | 2500.34            | NULL                   | NULL                  |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2009-08-09        | 7500.34            | 2500.34                | -5000                 |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2009-08-10        | 14500.34           | 7500.34                | -7000                 |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2009-08-10        | 1500.34            | 14500.34               | 13000                 |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2009-09-09        | 7500.34            | 1500.34                | -6000                 |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2009-09-09        | 2500.34            | 7500.34                | 5000                  |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2009-09-10        | 14500.34           | 1500.34                | -13000                |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2009-09-10        | 1500.34            | 2500.34                | 1000                  |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2010-08-09        | 7500.34            | 14500.34               | 7000                  |
| NSE            | INFY              | 2010-08-09        | 2500.34            | 7500.34                | 5000                  |
.....
.....
```

May anyone give me some clues to do this in an efficient way.

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hive window function `lag()` to solve this. You can read more about window functions in hive [here](https://acadgild.com/blog/windowing-functions-in-hive).

Here is the working [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bPkSNxkRKGFvSpLsbroxRJ/0) in `PostgreSQL`,  but same query works in `HIVE` as well.

```
select
 exchanged,
 stock_symbol,
 closing_date,
 closing_price,
 yesterday_price,
 (yesterday_price - closing_price) as diff_yesterday_price
from
(
    select
        *,
        lag(closing_price) over (partition by stock_symbol order by closing_date) as yesterday_price
    from stockExchange
) la

order by
    stock_symbol,
    closing_date
```